# How are operations performed in the data that is spilled in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I understand the reason for spill mentioned [here](https://spark.apache.org/faq.html#:%7E:text=Spark%27s%20operators%20spill%20data%20to%20disk%20if%20it%20does%20not%20fit%20in%20memory%2C%20allowing%20it%20to%20run%20well%20on%20any%20sized%20data.). I am confused on whether for the following transformations

1. The tasks are executed for the data that is already in memory and then the data in disk is read and transformations are applied.

or

2.The transformations are applied on the disk itself.

This might be an illogical question, but can someone explain as I am new to Computing.

Comment: AFAIK, the disk is only used to store the data and it is read back once memory is available for the processing.

Comment: So you mean once after the current partitions in memory on which all tasks have executed, the data that was spilled on disk gets loaded into memory and the lineage of tasks are executed?